# when there are unstaged changes in a branch or untracked files, in both cases while switching the branches, files get overwritten. How to avoid it?

Tags: git, git-switch

These steps have been followed to generate the scenario:

```
mkdir testrepo
cd testrepo
git init
touch readme
git add readme
git commit -m "add readme"
git switch -c newbranch
touch 1
git switch -
```

Now on `master` branch I can see `1`.

Moreover whatever changes are done in `1` will be overwritten in another branch when we switch with `git switch -`

Comment: "Moreover whatever changes are done in 1 will be overwritten in another branch when we switch with git switch -" Nope. If that would happen, Git won't let you switch.

Answer (score 1):

#### TL;DR

**Untracked files** are ignored: Git only tracks files that have been committed. `1` has not been committed; if `1` was tracked in the other branch, that would cause a conflict.

**Unstaged changes**: unstaged changes to files that are the same in both branches are kept; unstaged changes to files that are different between the branches cause a conflict.

#### Details

##### Untracked files

With the scenario you give, nothing unusual is happening. `1` is visible on the file system as an Untracked file before and after the switch, it's not in either branch. It won't get tracked until you commit it.

##### Files tracked in one branch but not the other

Once committed, then Git will mind the differences in that file between different branches.

Extending your scenario, let's commit `1`, then go back to `newbranch`:

```
git add 1
git commit -m"adding 1"
git switch -
```

now `1` is gone, because it's not in `newbranch`.

And let's create a conflict by touching 1 again:

```
touch 1
git switch -
```

which generates this error message:

```
error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by checkout:
        1
Please move or remove them before you switch branches.
Aborting
```

In summary, when you have a file that's not been committed*, if you change it and then switch branch, Git just ignores it and leaves it alone.

*By "not committed", I mean not committed in either the branch you're switching from or the branch you're switching to.

##### Unstaged changes in files that are identical in both branches

Now, in the title of the question, you also ask about unstaged changes.

Let's create unstaged changes:

```
echo asdf >> readme
git switch -
```

Here the switch happens without error and a `git diff` before and after would show the same output. When a file is identical in two branches, unstaged changes to that file are simply kept as is when you switch branch. The file is not modified by that operation, so it's safe.

##### Unstaged changes in files that are different in the two branches

Let's commit that change to `readme`, add more unstaged changes, and see what happens:

```
git add readme
git commit -m"changing readme"
echo qwer >> readme
git switch -
```

All was fine until the last command, which gave me this error:

```
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by checkout:
        readme
Please commit your changes or stash them before you switch branches.
Aborting
```

As the message says, we now have an unsafe operation, since Git needs to checkout the version of `readme` in the other branch, and that would destroy our unstaged changes, so it just won't do it.

If the changes you want to merge those changes into the other branch, you need to invoke a tool that does merging, like stash: `git stash; git switch; git stash pop`, which would give you a chance to fix any conflicts in the merging process.

Comment: Thanks much @joanis for detailed explanation. I appreciate it. Is there any way to prevent below scenarios?

1. when a file is untracked in both the branches, but still when we switch from one branch to another, it should give warning and prevent switching to safeguard data overwrite.

2. when a file is staged; and the modified in working directory, still when we switch from one branch to another, it should give warning and prevent switching to safeguard data overwrite.

Comment: So, as far as I know, Git will never overwrite data, those safeguards already exist. Is there a specific scenario you've seen where you've actually lost data by switching? In each case I describe as a conflict, Git gave me an error message and aborted the switch. If you have a scenario where you've lost data, edit the question to show how, and I'll analyze it.